# Columnstore vs. Hekaton Performance

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

1. Which technique is faster for data bulk upload to empty db table?
2. Which technique is faster for data inserts / updates to non-empty    db table?
3. Which technique is faster when reading data from    non-empty db table?

Answer (score 1):

That is such a broad question. The performance profile of the two storage engines has nothing in common.

Use Hekaton for OLTP workloads. Use Columnstore indexes for analytical queries. Just by the fact that any query of a Columnstore index must scan it in total disqualifies it for OLTP-style queries. The fact that Hekaton has extremely limited query plan shapes disqualifies it for OLAP applications.

So you basically have no choice because the applications do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Hekaton for 1 and 2.

Columnstore for 3. Specially if it requires a "table scan", like doing select count(...).